# When reserving an Amazon EC2 instance, what does it mean for the Platform to be the same?

Tags: amazon-ec2

In the user guide [1] , it is stated that for your on demand ec2 instances to be billed under your reserved instances, they have to match four criteria.

- the region,
- Availability Zone,
- instance type,
- and platform specified

The Platform is confusing, because I use a **custom Ubuntu AMI** and in the EC2 Dashboard, my Platform field is blank.

When choosing a Reserved Instance, you can choose from "Linux/UNIX " and "Linux/UNIX ( Amazon VPC ) "  , Red Hat , SUSE , etc.

So how will I get charged?

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/reserved-instances-fundamentals.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would choose "Linux/Unix". Flavors of Linux such as Redhat and SUSE include additional licensing fees not charged for other versions of linux, which is why they are considered separate platforms.

Comment: Any thoughts on where Ubuntu fits into the platform choice? And what about my use of a custom AMI. I have my own AMI which is a derivative of the Ubuntu AMI.

Comment: Anything other than SUSE or Redhat is going to be "Linux/Unix".